# Appending an item to a python list in the declaration statement list = [].append(val) is a NoneType

Tags: python

I am running into this situation while using chained methods in python. 
Suppose, I have the following code

```
hash = {}
key = 'a'
val = 'A'
hash[key] = hash.get(key, []).append(val)
```

The `hash.get(key, [])` returns a [] and I was expecting that dictionary would be `{'a': ['A']}`. However the dictionary is set as `{'a': None}`.
On looking this up further, I realised that this was occurring due to python lists.

```
list_variable = []
list_variable.append(val)
```

sets the list_variable as `['A']`
However, setting a list in the initial declaration

```
list_variable = [].append(val)
type(list_variable)
<type 'NoneType'>
```

What is wrong with my understanding and expectation that list_variable should contain ['A'] 
Why are the statements behaving differently?

Comment: Avoid using `list` as a variable name, it shadows the built-in `list()` method.

Comment: The problem occurred originally in the first code segment and there wasn't any variable name that can shadow the built in methods. Anyway, let me correct the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `.append()` function alters the list *in place* and thus always returns `None`. This is normal and expected behaviour. You do not *need* to have a return value as the list itself has already been updated.

Use the [`dict.setdefault()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) to set a default empty list object:

```
>>> hash = {}
>>> hash.setdefault('a', []).append('A')
>>> hash
{'a': ['A']}
```

You may also be interested in the [`collections.defaultdict` class](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> hash = defaultdict(list)
>>> hash['a'].append('A')
>>> hash
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'a': ['A']})
```

If you want to return a *new* list with the extra item added, use concatenation:

```
lst = lst + ['val']
```

Answer (score 0):

`append` operates in-place. However you can utilize setdefault in this case:

```
hash.setdefault(key, []).append(val)
```